# Delete all checked items rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, action, checked

i have array tasks[] with items from form

```
<%= check_box_tag "tasks[]", task.id %>
```

I see them in console

```
Processing by TasksController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?", "authenticity_token"=>"qo6JqGn0a1Yck1j67taz7kEu/ENBrwLg0xs4HbmAehNq7yMVB3llJWYgZvRNrWKPrZqYJtZIaS89EIBFIyDZTA==", "tasks"=>["7", "8"], "commit"=>"Trash All Checked", "id"=>"delete_all"}
```

But can't delete, action dont work

```
def delete_all
    Task.where(id: params[:id]).destroy_all
    redirect_to action: "index"
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IDs are present in `params[:tasks]`, so you have to write something like that:

```rb
def delete_all
  Task.where(id: params[:tasks]).destroy_all

  redirect_to action: "index"
end
```

Anyway, I'd recommed to change `tasks` to `tasks_ids` in the view and the controller. It's a more meaningful name.